# how to transpose a row to a column in sas

Tags: sas

Hi I want to transpose a row to column but I can't do it with transpose function. Could someone assist me?

My dataset is

```
variable  variable1 variable2 variable3
   Inclusion   .        yes       2
```

and I want

```
Incusion 
.
yes 
2
```

my exist code is

```
  proc transpose data=f ;
 id variable variable1 variable 2; 
var variable3 ; 
run;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transpose function"?  PROC TRANSPOSE can transpose 4 variables into one.  Show the code you tried and explain in what way it did not work.

Comment: my code is  proc transpose data=f ; id variable variable1 variable 2; var variable3 ; run;

Comment: You cannot have an ID variable that is missing on every observation.  And even it it did work by only listing one variable in the VAR statement your request would output only one observation.  Only real change would be changing the name of VARIABLE3 to something built from the values of the three ID variables.

Answer (score 0):

PROC TRANSPOSE works fine on such data.

```
data have;
  input variable :$32. variable1 variable2 $ variable3 ;
cards;
Inclusion   .        yes       2
;

proc transpose data=have out=want;
  var _all_;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs     _NAME_                    COL1

 1     variable     Inclusion
 2     variable1                                   .
 3     variable2    yes
 4     variable3                                   2
```

If you want the variable to be named 'Inclusion' then add an ID statement.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want;
  id variable;
  var variable1-variable3 ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs     _NAME_       Inclusion

 1     variable1               .
 2     variable2    yes
 3     variable3               2
```